# Converter Número em Reais

Tags: javascript

Estou querendo desenvolver um Simulador exemplo: de **1** real à **99** reais ele multiplica por **x10** e acima de **100** reais ele multiplica por **x11**.

Queria saber como converte os número do `campo1` para reais quando digitar?

***Código:***

```
<html>
   <body>
       <head>

       </head>
<script> 
function soma() 
{
form.campo4.value = (form.campo1.value*1) * (form.campo2.value*1)
$('form.campo1').priceFormat({
    prefix: 'R$ ',
    centsSeparator: ',',
    thousandsSeparator: '.'
});
}
</script>
<form name="form">
    <p> Simulador de Cash's</p>
<input name="campo1" type="text" value="" class="soma"><br> 
<input name="campo2" value="22" readonly><br> 
<input name="campo4" readonly><br>
<input type="button" onclick="soma()" value="CALCULAR">
</form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Depende, qual seria o valor monetário do `campo1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sugiro um plugin jQuery chamado *maskMoney* ([baixe aqui](http://www.fabiobmed.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/jquery.maskMoney.zip)). Ele adiciona máscara de moedas no campo que você especificar.

Para usá-lo, carregue na sua página com:

```
<script src="jquery.maskMoney.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

E chame o plugin com o script:

```
$(function(){
 $("input").maskMoney({symbol:'R$ ', 
showSymbol:false, thousands:'.', decimal:',', symbolStay: true});
 });
```

[Um bom tutorial de como usar o plugin.](http://www.fabiobmed.com.br/criando-mascaras-para-moedas-com-jquery/)

**[Fiddle para teste.](https://jsfiddle.net/s1h4tk9m/)**

Comment: Obrigado <3 Me Ajudou muito Deus te Abençoe

Answer (score 0):

deu certo aqui o link mais quando eu vou multiplicar ta dando NaN porque :?

```
<html>
   <body>
   <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.maskMoney.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script> 
function soma() 
{
form.campo4.value = (form.campo1.value*1) * (form.campo2.value*1) 
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
 $("#demo4").maskMoney({symbol:'R$ ', 
showSymbol:true, thousands:'.', decimal:',', symbolStay: true});
 })
</script>
<form name="form">
<input name="campo1" id="demo4"><br> 
<input name="campo2" value="22" id="demo3"><br>  
<input name="campo4" readonly><br>
<input type="button" onclick="soma()" value="Soma os Valores">
</form>
   </body>
</html>
```

ai o código testa em sua máquina pra você ver