# Como faço para converter números inteiros e com ponto em moeda real ex.: 10,00

Tags: javascript

Eu gostaria de converter esse código ele só ta aparecendo numeros com ponto por exemplo 8.66, 8, 8.95, 9...

eu gostaria de deixar em real brasileiro ex.: R$8,66

```
<script>
obj.totalCart = function() {
    var totalCart = 0;
    for(var item in cart) {
      totalCart += cart[item].price * cart[item].count;
    }
    return Number(totalCart.toFixed(2));
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Seria isso mesmo mais não sei onde colocar neste código

Comment: No lugar de `toFixed`, coloque o `toLocaleString`

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Formatar moeda brasileira em JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/181922/formatar-moeda-brasileira-em-javascript)

Comment: Não consegui implementar amigo, desculpe não manjo de javascript

Comment: Consegui irmão valeuuu!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considere que sua pergunta já existe [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/181922/formatar-moeda-brasileira-em-javascript) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/234308/converter-n%C3%BAmero-em-reais) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/188190/formatar-moeda-com-separador-de-milhar)

Segue algumas formas de fazer isso:

```js
var atual = 8.66;

//Formato com R$
var f = atual.toLocaleString('pt-br',{style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL'});

//Formato sem R$
var f2 = atual.toLocaleString('pt-br', {minimumFractionDigits: 2});

console.log(f);
console.log(f2);
```